# Receiving 400 Bad request when making S3 GET request

Tags: amazon-s3, delphi-xe, indy10

I am trying to make an AWS version 4 authorization signed GET request to S3, and receive a bad request error 400 `Code:InvalidRequest Message:Missing required header` for this request: `x-amz-content-sha256`

If I prefix the header with `"Authorization: "`, I get error `Code:InvalidArgument Message:Unsupported Authorization Type <ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName> <ArgumentValue>Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/20200408/eu-west-3/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=vdchzint97uwyt3g%2fjehszrc8zpkbjsx4tfqacsqfow%3d</ArgumentValue>`

I'm using Delphi XE5 with Indy's `TIdHTTP` component. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I have included my code below.

```pascal
begin
  bucket := 'mybucket.ata-test';
  obj := 'test.xml';
  region := 'eu-west-3';
  service := 's3';
  aws := 'amazonaws.com';
  YYYYMMDD := FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd', now);
  amzDate := FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd"T"hhnnss"Z"', TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(Now), TFormatSettings.Create('en-US'));
  emptyHash := lowercase(SHA256HashAsHex(''));
  host := Format('%s.%s.%s.%s', [bucket, service, region, aws]);
  url := Format('%s://%s.%s.%s.%s/%s', ['https', bucket, service, region, aws, obj]);

// *** 1. Build the Canonical Request for Signature Version 4 ***
  // HTTPRequestMethod
  CanonicalRequest := URLEncodeValue('GET') +#10;
  // CanonicalURI
  CanonicalRequest := CanonicalRequest + '/' + URLEncodeValue(obj) +#10;
  // CanonicalQueryString (empty just a newline)
  CanonicalRequest := CanonicalRequest +#10;
  // CanonicalHeaders
  CanonicalRequest := CanonicalRequest + 'host:' + Trim(host) +#10
                                       + 'x-amz-content-sha256:' + emptyHash +#10
                                       + 'x-amz-date:' + Trim(amzDate) +#10;
  // SignedHeaders
  CanonicalRequest := CanonicalRequest + 'host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date' +#10;
  // HexEncode(Hash(RequestPayload)) - (hash of an empty string)
  CanonicalRequest := CanonicalRequest + emptyHash;

// *** 2. Create a String to Sign for Signature Version 4 ***
  StringToSign := 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256' +#10
                  + amzDate +#10
                  + UTF8String(YYYYMMDD) +'/'+ UTF8String(region) +'/'+ UTF8String(service) +UTF8String('/aws4_request') +#10
                  + lowercase(SHA256HashAsHex(CanonicalRequest));

// *** 3. Calculate the Signature for AWS Signature Version 4 ***
  DateKey := CalculateHMACSHA256(YYYYMMDD, 'AWS4' + SecretAccessKey);
  DateRegionKey := CalculateHMACSHA256(region, DateKey);
  DateRegionServiceKey := CalculateHMACSHA256(service, DateRegionKey);
  SigningKey := CalculateHMACSHA256('aws4_request', DateRegionServiceKey);

  Signature := lowercase(UrlEncodeValue(CalculateHMACSHA256(StringToSign, SigningKey)));

// *** 4. Create Authorisation Header and Add the Signature to the HTTP Request ***
  AuthorisationHeader := 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential='+AccessIdKey+'/'+YYYYMMDD+'/'+region+'/'+service+'/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature='+signature;  
// (Gives <Code>InvalidRequest</Code> <Message>Missing required header for this request: x-amz-content-sha256</Message>)

// Have also tried
// AuthorisationHeader := 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential='+AccessIdKey+'/'+YYYYMMDD+'/'+region+'/'+service+'/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature='+signature;  
// (Gives <Code>InvalidArgument</Code> <Message>Unsupported Authorization Type</Message>)

// *** 5. Add Header and Make Request ***
  stm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    try
      Idhttp.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines := False;
      Idhttp.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', AuthorisationHeader);
      Idhttp.Get(URL, stm);
    except
      on PE: EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
        s := PE.ErrorMessage;
        Raise;
      end;
      on E: Exception do begin
        s := E.Message;
        Raise;
      end;
    end;

    stm.Position := 0;
    Memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(stm);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(stm);
  end; 
end;

function SHA256HashAsHex(const value: string): String;
/// used for stringtosign
var
  sha: TIdHashSHA256;
begin
  LoadOpenSSLLibrary;
  if not TIdHashSHA256.IsAvailable then
    raise Exception.Create('SHA256 hashing is not available!');
  sha := TIdHashSHA256.Create;
  try
    result := sha.HashStringAsHex(value, nil);
  finally
    sha.Free;
  end;
end;

function CalculateHMACSHA256(const value, salt: String): String;
/// used for signingkey
var
  hmac: TIdHMACSHA256;
  hash: TIdBytes;
begin
  LoadOpenSSLLibrary;
  if not TIdHashSHA256.IsAvailable then
    raise Exception.Create('SHA256 hashing is not available!');
  hmac := TIdHMACSHA256.Create;
  try
    hmac.Key := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
    hash := hmac.HashValue(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(value));
    Result := EncodeBytes64(TArray<Byte>(hash));
  finally
    hmac.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things I notice in your code:

- when creating the `YYYYMMDD` and `amzDate` values, you are calling `Now()` twice, which creates a race condition that has the *potential* of causing those variables to represent different dates.  Unlikely, but possible.  To avoid that, you should call `Now()` only 1 time and save the result to a local `TDateTime` variable, and then use that variable in all of your `FormatDateTime()` calls.

```pascal
dtNow := Now();
YYYYMMDD := FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd', dtNow);
amzDate := FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd"T"hhnnss"Z"', TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(dtNow), TFormatSettings.Create('en-US'));
```

- When using `TIdHTTP`'s `Request.CustomHeaders` property to set a custom `Authorization` header, make sure that you also set the `Request.BasicAuthentication` property to False as well, otherwise `TIdHTTP` may create its own `Authorization: Basic ...` header using its `Request.Username` and `Request.Password` properties.  You don't want two `Authorization` headers in your `GET` request.

```pascal
Idhttp.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
```

- You are using `x-amz-content-sha256` and `x-amz-date` headers in your authorization calculations, but you are not adding those headers to the actual HTTP request.  `TIdHTTP` will add the `Host` header for you, but you need to add the other headers yourself.

```pascal
Idhttp.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('x-amz-content-sha256', emptyHash);
Idhttp.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('x-amz-date', amzDate);
```

- Your `SHA256HashAsHex()` function is not specifying a byte encoding when calling Indy's `TIdHashSHA256.HashStringAsHex()` method (in fact, it is going out of its way to explicitly set the encoding to `nil`).  As such, Indy's default byte encoding will be used, which is US-ASCII (unless you set Indy's `GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable in the `IdGlobal` unit to something else).  However, your `CalculateHMACSHA256()` function is explicitly using UTF-8 instead.  Your `SHA256HashAsHex()` function should use `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` to match:

```pascal
result := sha.HashStringAsHex(value, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
```

- the input salt and output value for `CalculateHMACSHA256()` needs to be binary bytes, not strings, and certainly not base64-encoded or hex-encoded strings. Nothing in the [Calculate the Signature for AWS Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html) documentation mentions the use of base64 at all.

```pascal
var
  DateKey, RegionKey, ServiceKey, SigningKey: TArray<Byte>;
...

// *** 3. Calculate the Signature for AWS Signature Version 4 ***
DateKey := CalculateHMACSHA256(YYYYMMDD, TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('AWS4' + SecretAccessKey));
RegionKey := CalculateHMACSHA256(region, DateKey);
ServiceKey := CalculateHMACSHA256(service, RegionKey);
SigningKey := CalculateHMACSHA256('aws4_request', ServiceKey);

Signature := CalculateHMACSHA256Hex(StringToSign, SigningKey); 

... 

function CalculateHMACSHA256(const value: string; const salt: TArray<Byte>): TArray<Byte>;
/// used for signingkey
var
  hmac: TIdHMACSHA256;
  hash: TIdBytes;
begin
  LoadOpenSSLLibrary;
  if not TIdHashSHA256.IsAvailable then
    raise Exception.Create('SHA256 hashing is not available!');
  hmac := TIdHMACSHA256.Create;
  try
    hmac.Key := TIdBytes(salt);
    hash := hmac.HashValue(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(value));
    Result := TArray<Byte>(hash);
  finally
    hmac.Free;
  end;
end;

function CalculateHMACSHA256Hex(const value: string; const salt: TArray<Byte>): string;
var
  hash: TArray<Byte>;
begin
  hash := CalculateHMACSHA256(value, salt)
  Result := lowercase(ToHex(TIdBytes(hash)));
end;
```

Comment: I don't know what is intended by this (in the question, not your answer)... 
`Signature := lowercase(UrlEncodeValue(CalculateHMACSHA256(StringToSign, SigningKey)));` ...but the signature in SigV4 is supposed to be a string of hexadecimal digits only.  The one in the question is definitely incorrect... looks like base64 converted to lowercase. `vdchzint97uwyt3g%2fjehszrc8zpkbjsx4tfqacsqfow%3d`

Comment: Thank you Remy, that helped a lot, both in my understanding of headers and moving forward. The request is now being processed but refused with a 403 Forbidden "SignatureDoesNotMatch" and the message "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."
Having gone through aws docs again I believe I found a coding error, as Michael just pointed out, so I altered the line Result := EncodeBytes64(TArray<Byte>(hash)); to Result := ToHex(hash); in the CalculateHMACSHA256 function but am still receiving the same message.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks. I updated my answer with that info

Comment: @Jon that change is still wrong. See the update I just posted

Comment: That is my lack understanding with encoding, much improved now with your help thank you. I made the changes but am still receiving "SignatureDoesNotMatch". I have been through aws docs and my code again from start to finish and now that the encoding is correct really can't see why I am still receiving the same response.

Comment: @Jon then I suggest you stop testing on the live server and instead test your functions locally using the example inputs that Amazon provides in their documentation, and make you are getting the same outputs that Amazon documents. Only then should you continue testing on a live server. Also note that while UTF-8 is *preferred*, it is not *required*. Amazon documents that servers *may* use other charsets, so check the documentation for the live server you are trying to access.

Comment: Ok thank you Remy, I'll look into that and see if I can get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Sorted. Aws documentation states: "The following is the canonical request format that Amazon S3 uses to calculate a signature. For signatures to match, you must create a canonical request in this format:"
<HTTPMethod>\n
<CanonicalURI>\n
<CanonicalQueryString>\n
<CanonicalHeaders>\n
<SignedHeaders>\n
<HashedPayload>
An extra empty new line was required between CanonicalHeaders and SignedHeaders lines to work. Thank you Remy and Michael for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through a similar problem, I will leave my contribution here, because this post helped me to arrive at the solution.
In my case I needed to generate a signed url with a certain expiration time.

```pascal
    unit Data.Cloud.AmazonAPI.Utils;
    
    interface
    
      //See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html#query-string-auth-v4-signing-example
      //Use example:
      // MyUlrSigned := GetUrlPreSigned('mybucketname','/MyFolder/MyFile.zip','sa-east-1',3600);
    
      function GetUrlPreSigned(ABucket:string;AObjectName:string;ARegion:string;AExpiresIn:Int64=3600):string;
    
    implementation
    
    uses
      System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.Hash, System.DateUtils;
    
    const
     
      AWS_ACCOUNTNAME     = '<AWSAccessKeyId>';
      AWS_ACCOUNTKEY      = '<AWSSecretAccessKey>';
    
    function SignString(const Signkey: TBytes; const StringToSign: string): TBytes;
    begin
      Result := THashSHA2.GetHMACAsBytes(StringToSign, Signkey);
    end;
    
    function BuildSignature(const StringToSign, DateISO, Region:string; AService: string; LSecretAccessKey:string): string;
    
      function GetSignatureKey(const datestamp, region, serviceName: string): TBytes;
      begin
        Result := SignString(TEncoding.Default.GetBytes('AWS4'+LSecretAccessKey) ,datestamp);
        Result := SignString(Result, region);
        Result := SignString(Result, serviceName);
        Result := SignString(Result, 'aws4_request');
      end;
    
    var
      Signature:string;
      SigningKey : TBytes;
    begin
      SigningKey := GetSignatureKey(DateISO, Region, AService);
      Result  := THash.DigestAsString(SignString(SigningKey, StringToSign));
    end;
    
    function GetHashSHA256Hex( HashString: string): string;
    var
      LBytes: TArray<Byte>;
    begin
      LBytes := THashSHA2.GetHashBytes(HashString);
      Result := THash.DigestAsString(LBytes);
    end;
    
    function GetUrlPreSigned(ABucket:string;AObjectName:string;ARegion:string;AExpiresIn:Int64=3600):string;
    var
      LNow : TDateTime;
      LData : string;
      LTimeStamp : string;
      LAccessKey : string;
      LSecretAccessKey : string;
      LService : string;
      LAws : string;
      LHost : string;
      LUrl : string;
      LQueryParams : string;
      LCanonicalRequest : string;
      LStringToSign : string;
      LSignature : string;
    begin
      LNow := Now();
      LData := FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd', LNow);
      LTimeStamp :=  FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd"T"hhnnss"Z"', TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(LNow), TFormatSettings.Create('en-US'));
      LAccessKey       := AWS_ACCOUNTNAME;
      LSecretAccessKey := AWS_ACCOUNTKEY;
    
      if AObjectName.StartsWith('/') then
        Delete(AObjectName,1,1);
    
      LService := 's3';
      LAws := 'amazonaws.com';
      LHost := Format('%s-%s.%s', [LService, ARegion, LAws]);
      LUrl := Format('%s://%s-%s.%s/%s/%s', ['https', LService, ARegion, LAws, ABucket, AObjectName]);
    
      LQueryParams := 'X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential='+LAccessKey
                      +'%2F'+LData
                      +'%2F'+ARegion
                      +'%2F'+LService+'%2F'
                      +'aws4_request'
                      +'&X-Amz-Date='+LTimeStamp
                      +'&X-Amz-Expires='+AExpiresIn.ToString
                      +'&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host';
    
      //1 - CanonicalRequest
      LCanonicalRequest := 'GET' +#10+
                        '/'+ABucket+'/'+AObjectName +#10
                        +LQueryParams +#10
                        +'host:'+LHost+#10
                        +#10
                        +'host'+#10
                        +'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD';
    
      //2 - StringToSign
      LStringToSign := 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256' +#10
                      + LTimeStamp +#10
                      + UTF8String(LData)+'/'+ UTF8String(ARegion) +'/'+ UTF8String(LService)+UTF8String('/aws4_request') +#10
                      + lowercase(GetHashSHA256Hex(LCanonicalRequest));
      //3 - Signature
      LSignature := BuildSignature(LStringToSign,LData,ARegion,LService,LSecretAccessKey);
    
      //4 - Signed URL
      Result := LUrl+'?'+LQueryParams+'&X-Amz-Signature='+LSignature;
    end;
    
    end.
```